# Made a jquery plugin and it works but I have one last thing I can't figure out

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I tried searching around for an answer but Im not sure how to word it without explaining it first. Anyway, this is an example of how I call my plugin:

```
$('body').myPlugin({container: 'exampleA', amount:4});
```

The thing is, where is says 'body' seems to be useless, I can put any element there and it works fine. I would rather it say something like....

```
$('.exampleA').myPlugin({amount:4});
```

...and then tell the plugin to use exampleA for container. Am I correct in thinking that is indeed possible? How would I modify my plugin to achieve this?

Here is an example of my plugin:

```
(function($){
 $.fn.extend({
     myPlugin: function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            container : 'list_container',
            amount : 2
        }
        var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var o = options;
            //Start
            $('.'+o.container+' ul').each(function(){
               //DO STUFF HERE....
            });
            //End
        });
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

I can post the actual code/plugin if I need to, I just thought it might be easier to explain what I'm trying to do if I posted a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
        amount: 2
    }
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    return this.each(function () {
        $('ul', this).each(function () {
            //DO STUFF
        });
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NWQJV/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew it had to be something simple like that, I just didn't know what

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($){
 $.fn.extend({
 myPlugin: function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        container : 'list_container',
        amount : 2
    }
    var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
    return this.each(function() {
        var o = options;
        //Start
        $(this).children('ul').each(function(){
           //DO STUFF HERE....
        });
        //End
    });
}
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in your plugin is the jQuery selection. If you use `find` on this collection, then it should be scoped to containers inside of selected elements.

```
$.fn.extend({
    myPlugin: function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            container : 'list_container',
            amount : 2
        }
        var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
        this.find('.' + options.container + ' ul').each(function(){
           //DO STUFF HERE....
        });
    });
}
```